# Why Does MongoDB Give an Out Of Disk Space Error When Space Is Available?

Tags: fedora, mongodb

I am running RocketChat on a Fedora 27 (64bit) server and it uses MongoDB. Details are currently:

```
Version of Rocket.Chat Server: 0.64.0-rc.0
Operating System: Fedora 27 64 bit
Deployment Method(snap/docker/tar/etc): tar
Number of Running Instances: 1
Node Version: 8.9.4
mongoDB Version: 3.4.11
```

Roughly every 24 hours the instance crashes and I have to restart the mongod service to get it up and running again.

I can see the following in the log:

2018-04-18T00:07:47.635+0000 E STORAGE [thread2] WiredTiger error (28) [1524010067:625767][8003:0x7fae865e9700], file:index-545-5179165362493312193.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: /var/lib/mongodb/index-545-5179165362493312193.wt: handle-write: pwrite: failed to write 4096 bytes at offset 28672: No space left on device
2018-04-18T00:07:47.637+0000 E STORAGE [thread2] WiredTiger error (28) [1524010067:637297][8003:0x7fae865e9700], file:index-545-5179165362493312193.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: index-545-5179165362493312193.wt: fatal checkpoint failure: No space left on device

There is over 12GB of free space on the partition that hosts the mongod database, so I am unclear what the cause of this is. The server uses KVM and not OpenVZ.

Anyone have a clue what might be causing this?

Comment: What file system are you using and what is the output of `df -i` for the partition with your `/var/lib/mongodb` directory ? How are you attaching your storage in Docker/?

Comment: hi, filesystem is ext4. I am not using Docker, Rocket Chat is installed via a downloaded .tar.

output is:

Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
devtmpfs        501926     391  501535    1% /dev
tmpfs           504861      30  504831    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           504861     577  504284    1% /run
tmpfs           504861      17  504844    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1      3840000 1010068 2829932   27% /
tmpfs           504861      56  504805    1% /tmp
tmpfs           504861       6  504855    1% /run/user/1000

Answer (score 0):

In the end I discovered that this problem was caused by other processes in the system that were exhausting the storage temporarily. case closed.